# Time format is not working with QApplication (PyQt4)

Tags: python, time, pyqt4, python-3.5

I'm currently working on a script using Python3.5 that uses the libs: logging and PyQt4.

The log format config is using the format am/pm (%I:%M:%S %p).

I'd identified that when instanciating QApplication, the time pattern %p was missed from log. I think that this issue is native of pyqt4, but if someone have another suggestion I appreciate.

```
In [1]: import sys, time
In [2]: print(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p'))
02:29:51 PM
In [3]: from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
In [4]: print(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p'))
02:29:59 PM
In [5]: app = QApplication(sys.argv)
In [6]: print(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p'))
02:30:05
```

Python version: 3.5.2

PyQt4 version: 4.8.7

Comment: I do not reproduce that problem: https://imgur.com/a/DUdGU, Python 3.6.4, PyQt4 4.12.1

Comment: I very much doubt that you are using pyqt-4.8.7. You probably mean you are using **qt**-4.8.7. So what specific version of *pyqt* are you really using, and on which specific platform(s)? It would also be useful if you could provide some details about your locale.

Comment: PS: the [qt locale settings](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#locale-settings) may be the cause of this behaviour. Try `import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')` after creating the app object. To restore the system settings, use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, it's works using locale.